# Silverlight-Hiding item in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, data-binding

I have an ItemsControl.I want to hide the Text Box  in the ItemsControl DataTemplete on some  Flag. But when i access the Text Box in Code Behind File .it gives the error doesn't exists in the current context.Is there a way to do this using SilverLight?

Answer (score 0):

Let's go by parts, in case you are not using MVVM, due to you are using a DataTemplate the Control is not added as usual in the visual tree, so you can do the following, add to the TextBox the LoadedEvent, and create a List in order to have all the TextBoxes inside, and there you can do what you need when you want.

In case you are using Binding with MVVM, you can bind the property of that control, like the Text with Mode=TwoWay or the Visibility with a bool and adding a converter.

That is a general answer to your general question, in case you need more details, please add the specific code you are using.